# Unify squared distance matrices c#

Tags: c#, matrix

I need to unify two different square matrices into one.

We are in need of cacheing a very large distance matrix.

We are using a maps provider that charges per call, so we need to make many small calls and then unify the matrices in to one matrix.
For the matrix cell that are not calculated we can insert a very big number, let's say inf

So let me elaborate (for the sake of simplicity let's say we have two matrices):

```
       a b c d
a = a [0 5 2 6]
    b [5 0 7 3]
    c [2 7 0 9]
    d [6 3 9 0]

       e f g
b = e [0 5 8]
    f [5 0 18]
    g [8 18 0]
```

I need to create the following matrix

```
       a   b   c   d   e   f   g
c = a [0   5   2   6  inf inf inf]
    b [5   0   7   3  inf inf inf]
    c [2   7   0   9  inf inf inf]
    d [6   3   9   0  inf inf inf]
    e [inf inf inf inf 0   5   8 ]
    f [inf inf inf inf 5   0   18]
    g [inf inf inf inf 8   18   0]
```

Is there a library known for unifying such matrices or I should build it from scratch?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why do you need those "inf" in the resulting array?

Comment: I don't need. Might as well be anything. I need it to be a big number to "prevent" some links, because its for a routing application.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest in-build option to merge 2 arrays is [Concat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat?view=net-5.0)

```
double[][] a = {
    new double[] { -1, -2, -1, -2 },
    new double[] { -5, -3, -4, -2 },
    new double[] { -1, -2, -1, -2 },
    new double[] { -5, -3, -4, -2 }
};

double[][] b = {
    new double[] {1, 1, -1 },
    new double[] { 3, 2, 3 },
    new double[] { -5, -3, -4}
};

double[][] result = a.Concat(b).ToArray();

foreach (var line in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(',', line));
}
```

If you have any strong reasons to have "inf" in your resulting matrix, more likely you have to extend your initial arrays manually with something like `int.MaxValue`

Comment: Hello Boris. I nee the matrix to be a euclidean square matrix, that's why I have to append the extra produced values.

Comment: This does not produce the requested output.

Answer (score 0):

I have crafted a piece of code which does what I am asking. Creates a euclidean square matrix from two different size matrices by adding a large value on their connections

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, double>> firstMatrix
                = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, double>>>(originalMatrixText);
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, double>> secondMatrix
                = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, double>>>(secondaryMatrixText);

//Create the dimension of the full matrix
List<string> totalPoints = new List<string>();
totalPoints.AddRange(firstMatrix.Keys);
totalPoints.AddRange(secondMatrix.Keys);

Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, double>> finalMatrix = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, doube>>();

foreach (string pointA in totalPoints)
{
    string keyRow = pointA;
    Dictionary<string, double> cells = new Dictionary<string, double>();

    if (!finalMatrix.ContainsKey(keyRow))
    {
        foreach (string pointB in totalPoints)
        {
            string keyCell = pointB;
            double distance = 0;
            if (!cells.ContainsKey(keyCell))
            {
                if (firstMatrix.ContainsKey(keyRow) && firstMatrix.ContainsKey(keyCell))
                {
                    //If the element was in the first matrix use this value
                    distance = firstMatrix[keyRow][keyCell];
                }
                else if (secondMatrix.ContainsKey(keyRow) && secondMatrix.ContainsKey(keyCell))
                {
                    //If the element was in the second matrix use this value
                    distance = secondMatrix[keyRow][keyCell];
                }
                else
                {
                    //If the element did not exist in either matrix use the max Value of Double
                    distance = double.MaxValue;
                }
                cells.Add(keyCell, distance);
            }
        }
        finalMatrix.Add(keyRow, cells);
    }
}
```